# can't find variable javascript error

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to run a  slideshow presentation tool ,and the following code is suppose to initialize the slideshow ,but I get an error which goes like 'uncaught reference error: reveal is not defined', which I don't understand cause the code simply has to start the slideshow.
Here's the code:

```
Reveal.initialize({
    // Display controls in the bottom  right corner
    controls: true,
    // Display a presentation progress bar
    progress: false,
    // Click above progress bar for quick  navigation - only works if progress is true
    progressNavigation: true,
    // If true; each slide will be pushed  to the browser history
    history: false,
    // Flags if mouse wheel navigation  should be enabled
    mouseWheel: true,
    // Apply a 3D roll to links on hover
    rollingLinks: true,
    // UI style
    theme: query.theme || 'default', //  default/neon
    // Transition style
    transition: query.transition || 'concave' // default/cube/page/concave/linear(2d)
});
```

awaiting enlightenment.Thanks.

Comment: Seems like `Reveal` does not exist... you have to include the appropriate script before you can use it. Since we don't know what library you are using this is all that can be said.

Answer (score 0):

this goes in head

```
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.css">

               /* jQuery needs to be attached */
               <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

               /* Then just attach the Reveal plugin */
               <script src="jquery.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and obivously, you have to download each of those and put them in your project - on the website there is a link that Says Download, thats where you get it

Comment: there are actually more then one reveal plugins , so I don't know which one you are using, but you get the point, download , add reference in head , then you can use it in script

Comment: I've included all the relevant libraries and script but it still wants a variable

Comment: did you download this https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/downloads , then don't just copy and paste my code, but put a real source

Comment: I see you copied that source in your question right from github page,  did you also copy correctly the part about how to format the HTML ? the div id's have to match exactly for the plugin to work

Comment: I failed to present the question correctly- yes the link I put is the original one ,but I'm fiddling with the modified simpler version I found http://www.physics.byu.edu/faculty/durfee/Reveal/RevealSimpleExample.html -my apologies - As to your last  comment- well I'm lost. So far when I load the file ,I get a blank background and the error, I don't understand what which id's you mean.